# localization in asp.net using resource files

Tags: asp.net, resources, localization

I am developing a bilingual web application in asp.net and ive ran into a blocker while trying to implement the bilingual system using a resource file. I have three four resource files in the "asp.net special folder App_GlobalResources" namely

common.resx
pages.resx
reports.resx

All the files contains respective key value pairs which i ve used in my application. Now i also have another set of resource files in the same folder for french with suffix "_fr".

When a user clicks change language in the page i want the application to use the _fr suffix resource files. Is this doable?

Comment: Yes that is possible. You have to change culture and uiculture.

Comment: that is possible.. Change Culture

Answer (score 0):

Resource file with given culture will be selected automatically. You just have to override the `InitializeCulture()` page method.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        base.InitializeCulture();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture  = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this once. It may help u
[Globalizating and localizing WebSite](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6997/0/page/1)